# Oracle Apex Interactive Grid Disable a ROW based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex-20.2, interactive-grid

I have a table called `TABLE_A` with fields `ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, AGE, STATUS`.

From this table i have an interactive grid in ORACLE APEX 20.2 and i want when the status is approved then the entire row of that record in the grid to be disabled (not editable). I have done research but they are spoke and describe COLUMN DISABLING. I do not want to disable column based on a condition, i want to disable a row.

In oracle apex, i used the **read-only** feature on the interactive grid. With the read-only feature, i had a sql query on rows returned as shown below but when i use this, it makes the entire gird is not editable:

SQL Query When Rows Returned

```
select 1 from TABLE_A where upper(STATUS) = 'APPROVED';
```

Screenshot From Oracle Apex

[image]

[image]

One link to what i research:
https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4482243/oracle-apex-lock-disable-specific-columns-in-interactive-grid

Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by 'Disable'? What is the expected result?

Comment: The row should not be editiable, when i used the read-only feature, it makes the entire grid not editable

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know how many different `status` do you have. But I assume there are only two values in this column: `Approved` and `Not Approved`

Then you can try this query:

```
select a.* , decode(UPPER(a.status),'NOT APPROVED','U' ,'X') as EDITABLE  from TABLE_A a
```

Then you should use `Alowed row operation column` in Apex.

After creating the column, click on the Attributes node of the interactive grid and specify the EDITABLE column for the Allowed Row Operations Column property.

[image]

This tool allows data to be changed according to different values:

- U – allow row update
- D – allow row delete
- UD – allow both Update and Delete
- If anything else is returned the row will not be editable.

Comment: What is "X" for, what does it represent?

Comment: What did you use as the source of this column? It is not a database column

Comment: I have tried this but it continue to make the entire grid not editable

Comment: X is anything but not U or D or UD. I used a column with "Approved - Not Approved" "Varchar" like your status column.

Comment: It worked after a few tries, I dont know if the system was buggy haha. But thank you!